# AutoComplete Text Box in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I want to read the data through the auto complete text box through code behind. but i dont know how to get this.

here is the code.

```
List<string> suggestions=new List<string>();
suggestions.Add("First");
suggestions.Add("2nd");
suggestions.Add("3rd");
auto1.ItemSource=suggestions;
```

auto1 is the name of AutoComplete TextBox. but it shows the suggestions. but when i read data from auto1 through

```
auto1.Text.ToString();
```

it shows null.how to get data.

Comment: https://github.com/StanleyGoldman/TeamPilgrim/blob/master/lib/Extended.Wpf.Toolkit.1.8.0/Extended.Wpf.Toolkit.1.8.0.nuspec

This library has an auto complete textbox . you can get via nuget

Comment: Is this already the Autocomplete Textbox from Xcced's extended toolkit?

Comment: yes, from WPFToolKit from https://www.nuget.org/packages/WPFToolkit/

Comment: and you have choosen an auto completed string from your ItemsSource and then called auto1.Text.ToString(); 
where is that code called ?